# Cannot install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 on clean install Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: visual-c++, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, redistributable

Huge issue I have experienced with Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 or 2017 Redistributable package install. Windows 8.1 Pro installation is absolutely clean. I need to perform this in order to install KB2999266 Universal C Runtime (CRT) which requires this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Make sure you are starting with Windows 8.1 Update (a.k.a. KB2919355)

Comment: Do clean install with 8.1 November 2014 ISO, now you have all requirements to be able to install KB2999266